# `class = fb-comments`: The tagged people are not displayed as links on the wall

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a `div` tag with `fb-comments` as the class attribute value.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="students.com/library" 
data-width="495" data-numposts="5" data-mobile="mobile"></div>
```

In this link, I attempted to tag a person, say `Andy Apple` using `@Andy Apple`. I also checked the `Also Post on Facebook` box. On the link's comments, it is displayed as Andy being tagged. However, on my Facebook wall, I cannot see Andy being tagged.

Is this a feature by Facebook or did I implement it wrongly? Please ask me if I need to provide new information about this question.

Comment: I would suggest to fill a bug if this behaviour is still happening: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs